Why do the addresses of my variables not change after function is done processing in my assembly (HLA) program?
I'm trying to change the addresses of the variables once the procedure is done processing the instructions. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it. For example when I input
Gimme X: 12
Gimme Y: 1
Gimme Z: 50
I get this
After biggest, X = 12 Y = 1 Z = 50
when it should be After biggest, X = 50, Y = 50, Z = 50
This is my code so far, any help is greatly appreciated.

program BiggestValue;
#include("stdlib.hhf");

static
    x: int16;
    y: int16;
    z: int16;

procedure biggest(var x: int16; var y: int16; var z: int16); @nodisplay; @noframe;
static
    maxValue: int16;
begin biggest;

    // Load addresses of x, y, and z into registers
    lea(ebx, x);         // ebx = address of x
    lea(ecx, y);         // ecx = address of y
    lea(edx, z);         // edx = address of z

    // Load values pointed by x, y, and z
    mov((type int16 [ebx]), ax);  // ax = value at address x
    mov((type int16 [ecx]), bx);  // bx = value at address y
    mov((type int16 [edx]), cx);  // cx = value at address z

    // Find the maximum value
    mov(ax, maxValue);   // maxValue = value at x
    cmp(bx, maxValue);
    jle skip_y;
    mov(bx, maxValue);   // maxValue = value at y
    skip_y:
    cmp(cx, maxValue);
    jle skip_z;
    mov(cx, maxValue);   // maxValue = value at z
    skip_z:

    // Set x, y, and z to maxValue
    mov(maxValue, (type int16 [ebx]));  // value at address x = maxValue
    mov(maxValue, (type int16 [ecx]));  // value at address y = maxValue
    mov(maxValue, (type int16 [edx]));  // value at address z = maxValue

end biggest;

begin BiggestValue;

    // Get input from the user
    stdout.put("Gimme X: ");
    stdin.get(x);
    stdout.put("Gimme Y: ");
    stdin.get(y);
    stdout.put("Gimme Z: ");
    stdin.get(z);

    // Call the biggest procedure
    biggest(x, y, z);

    // Print the results
    stdout.put("After biggest, X = ", x, " Y = ", y, " Z = ", z, nl);

end BiggestValue;

